# Text input top and left border appears wrong

Tags: html, css

I have a text input but the color is not right on top and left border, why is this, and how can I fix this?

http://jsfiddle.net/9ehBs/

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="searchbox" />
```

**CSS**

```
.searchbox
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: Ebrima;
    color: rgb(54,54,54);
    border-width: 13px;
    border-color: rgb(46,94,115);
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: its using a default border-style, you want border-style: solid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `border-style: solid`. [See your updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/9ehBs/1/)

It would be much more efficient to use the [shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border), i.e. `border: 13px solid rgb(46,94,115);`

Comment: Lol, I wanted to add your edit in a comment, but since you included it in the answer +1

Answer (score 1):

```
border: 13px solid rgb(46,94,115);
```

easier in one row ... hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
.searchbox
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: Ebrima;
    color: rgb(54,54,54);
    border-width: 13px;
    border-style: solid;/* add this to your css options: dotted | solid | dashed */
    border-color: rgb(46,94,115);
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

shorthand writing:

```
margin: 10px 0 0 10px; /*(top, right and left, bottom)*/
border:13px solid rgb(46,94,115);
```

...instead of

```
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;


border-width: 13px;
border-style: solid;/* add this to your css options: dotted | solid | dashed */
border-color: rgb(46,94,115);
```